# Android can only be built with make version 3.81

Tags: android, makefile, android-source

So if Android can be compiled with make v3.81 I installed it as

```
/usr/bin/make-3.81
```

But make 4.0 is in my path as well under

```
/usr/bin/make
```

My question is if I execute

```
$ make-3.81 clean && make-3.81 -j8
```

Is it safe and build like that, or will it try to call "make" from my PATH somewhere during build and run ito make v4.0?

So in other words, should I make sure only "make" version 3.81 is in my PATH when building Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the makefiles are properly written and always uses the variable `$(MAKE)` anywhere they want to invoke make recursively, it will work fine.  If someone has written poor makefiles and used the explicit command `make`, then it will break.

Comment: Thanks. I saw lots "$(MAKE)" in makefiles so it must be okay. I was wandering if the "$(MAKE)" itself calls make which uses the makefile or make which it finds in PATH.

Comment: The `MAKE` variable is set to whatever name make was invoked as, and that's the only thing it's ever set to.